# Convert container of pointers to smart pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, stl, smart-pointers

Is there a concise, generic way to convert a `std` container (such as `vector`) of regular/dumb pointers:

```
vector< T* >
```

to, for instance, `boost::shared_ptr`?:

```
vector< boost::shared_ptr<T> >
```

I thought I could pull it off using `vector`'s range constructor:

```
vector< T* > vec_a;
...
vector< boost::shared_ptr<T> > vec_b( vec_a.begin(), vec_a.end() );
```

but that refused to compile (Visual Studio 2008).

EDIT: Test code:

```
void test()
{
    vector< int* > vec_a;
    vector< boost::shared_ptr<int> > vec_b( vec_a.begin(), vec_a.end() );
}
```

Compilation errors:

```
1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\memory(131) : error C2664: 'std::allocator<_Ty>::construct' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'int *' to 'const boost::shared_ptr<T> &'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=boost::shared_ptr<int>
1>        ]
1>        and
1>        [
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>        Reason: cannot convert from 'int *' to 'const boost::shared_ptr<T>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>        Constructor for class 'boost::shared_ptr<T>' is declared 'explicit'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>        c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\memory(822) : see reference to function template instantiation '_FwdIt std::_Uninit_copy<int**,_FwdIt,_Alloc>(_InIt,_InIt,_FwdIt,_Alloc &,std::_Nonscalar_ptr_iterator_tag,std::_Range_checked_iterator_tag)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _FwdIt=boost::shared_ptr<int> *,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<int>>,
1>            _InIt=int **
1>        ]
1>        c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\vector(1141) : see reference to function template instantiation '_FwdIt stdext::unchecked_uninitialized_copy<_Iter,boost::shared_ptr<T>*,std::allocator<_Ty>>(_InIt,_InIt,_FwdIt,_Alloc &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _FwdIt=boost::shared_ptr<int> *,
1>            _Iter=std::_Vector_iterator<int *,std::allocator<int *>>,
1>            T=int,
1>            _Ty=boost::shared_ptr<int>,
1>            _InIt=std::_Vector_iterator<int *,std::allocator<int *>>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<int>>
1>        ]
1>        c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\vector(956) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::shared_ptr<T> *std::vector<_Ty>::_Ucopy<_Iter>(_Iter,_Iter,boost::shared_ptr<T> *)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int,
1>            _Ty=boost::shared_ptr<int>,
1>            _Iter=std::_Vector_iterator<int *,std::allocator<int *>>
1>        ]
1>        c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\vector(889) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::vector<_Ty>::_Insert<_Iter>(std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>,_Iter,_Iter,std::forward_iterator_tag)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=boost::shared_ptr<int>,
1>            _Iter=std::_Vector_iterator<int *,std::allocator<int *>>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<int>>
1>        ]
1>        c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\vector(537) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::vector<_Ty>::insert<_Iter>(std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>,_Iter,_Iter)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=boost::shared_ptr<int>,
1>            _Iter=std::_Vector_iterator<int *,std::allocator<int *>>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<int>>
1>        ]
1>        c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\vector(514) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::vector<_Ty>::_Construct<_Iter>(_Iter,_Iter,std::input_iterator_tag)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=boost::shared_ptr<int>,
1>            _Iter=std::_Vector_iterator<int *,std::allocator<int *>>
1>        ]
1>        .\test.cpp(8364) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::vector<_Ty>::vector<std::_Vector_iterator<int,_Alloc>>(_Iter,_Iter)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=boost::shared_ptr<int>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<int *>,
1>            _Iter=std::_Vector_iterator<int *,std::allocator<int *>>
1>        ]
```

Comment: What error were you getting in VS2008?

Comment: @templatetypedef: boost::shared_ptr does not allow implicit construction from raw pointer (because that might hide a change of semantics), so the compiler will consider the types unrelated.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Added my test stub and errors

Comment: Consider using `::std::tr1::shared_ptr` if you can.  It's nice to avoid dependencies on third party libraries, even ones as spectacular as boost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Combine `::std::back_inserter` with `::std::transform` and a little function that will perform the conversion.  If you also use `reserve`, this should be reasonably efficient.  Once all the templates are expanded you will essentially get this code:

```
template <class T>
static inline ::std::tr1::shared_ptr<T> to_shared_ptr(T *val)
{
   return ::std::tr1::shared_ptr<T>(val);
}

void test()
{
   ::std::vector< int* > vec_a;
   ::std::vector< ::std::tr1::shared_ptr<int> > vec_b;
   vec_b.reserve(vec_a.size());
   ::std::transform(vec_a.begin(), vec_a.end(), ::std::back_inserter(vec_b),
                    to_shared_ptr<int>);
   vec_a.clear();
}
```

Comment: ITYM `return ::std::tr1::shared_ptr<T>(val);`

Answer (score 9):

You could use `std::transform`:

```
  template <typename T>
  boost::shared_ptr<T> to_shared_ptr(T * p) { return boost::shared_ptr<T>(p); }

  vec_b.resize(vec_a.size());  
  std::transform(vec_a.begin(), vec_a.ebd(), vec_b.begin(), to_shared_ptr);
```

*However*, the recommended practice is to assign raw pointers to smart pointers immediately after creation. Having the raw pointers put in a container, then copying them to another another container looks dangerous. YOu need to make sure noone else ever frees these raw pointers. You could emphasize that by `vec_a.clear()` immediately after the transfer - but that's far from a guarantee.

Comment: I'm working with a legacy API that wants to append to a `vector<T*>` passed in by reference.  I was hoping to make my usage of it slightly safer.

Comment: You also need to make sure nobody uses the raw pointers after the smart pointer has freed the memory, just to add to the fun.

Comment: @genpfault: I presumed you have a legitimate reason. If the legacy API says "you have to delete them when you are done with them, and I'll never look at them again", you should be fine.

Comment: @peterchen: Yep, those are the exact semantics I'm working with.

Comment: If you want to use `vec_b.begin()` as the output iterator, then you need to make space in `vec_b` first, via the constructor or with `resize()` not `reserve()`. If you want to just `reserve()` (or do nothing), then you need `back_inserter(vec_b)` as the output iterator.

Answer (score 7):

According to [the documentation of Boost `shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm), the `shared_ptr` constructor is marked `explicit`, meaning that there's no implicit conversion from `T*`s to `shared_ptr<T>`.  Consequently, when you're trying to insert the iterator range defining your old container into the new container, the compiler complains because there's no way of implicitly converting from the raw pointers of the old containers into the `shared_ptr`s of the new container.  You can fix this by either using a `back_inserter` and `transform`, or by just doing the iteration by hand to wrap each pointer and insert it one at a time.

It turns out that there's a good reason that you don't want this conversion to work implicitly.  Consider:

```
void DoSomething(shared_ptr<T> ptr) {
     /* ... */
}

T* ptr = new T();
DoSomething(ptr);
```

If the implicit conversion were allowed here, then the call to `DoSomething` would be legal.  However, this would cause a new `shared_ptr` to start referencing the resource held by `ptr`.  This is problematic, because when this `shared_ptr` goes out of scope when `DoSomething` returns, it will see that it's the only `shared_ptr` to the resource and will deallocate it.  In other words, calling `DoSomething` with a raw pointer would implicitly delete the pointer!

Answer (score 3):

Just because you said `for instance, boost::shared_ptr` - if the semantics fit you, there is `boost::ptr_vector` which stores a vector of pointers and is responsible for freeing them when the vector goes out of scope. This container has a `transfer` method that you could use for taking ownership of the pointers cointained in the vector you get.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the range constructor like so:

```
vector<int*> nums = { new int(1), new int(5), new int(10) };
vector<shared_ptr<int>> smart_nums(nums.begin(), nums.end());
```

Conceptually it is equivalent to:

```
for (int num : nums)
    smart_nums.emplace_back(num);
```

Now with the range constructor, the following is possible:

```
class Num_container {
public:
    Num_container(vector<int*> nums)
        : smart_nums(nums.begin(), nums.end()) { }
private:
    vector<shared_ptr<int>> smart_nums;
};
```

This makes dealing with containers of polymorphic types much easier!